# How to pass array instead of cell names in phpexcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel

```
<?php
require_once 'PHPExcel.php';
require_once 'config.php';


// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

// Set document properties
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Maarten Balliauw")
                             ->setLastModifiedBy("Maarten Balliauw")
                             ->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
                             ->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
                             ->setDescription("Test document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.")
                             ->setKeywords("office 2007 openxml php")
                             ->setCategory("Test result file");

$aRows[] = array("No.","Dealer Name","Mobile No.","Phone No.","Address","Credit Limit","Pending Amount","Status","Total Amount","Order No.","Estimate Arrival","Docket No.");
            $aRows[] = array("","","","","","","","","","","","");
$qry = "SELECT * FROM register "; 
$qry=mysqli_query($conn , $qry);
while($d= mysqli_fetch_array($qry)){

$aRows[]=array("","","","Item Details","","","");
                    $aRows[]=array("","","","","","","","","","","","");
                    $aRows[]=array("","ID","First Name","Last Name","Email");

                            $aRows[]=array("",$d[0],$d[1],$d[2],$d[3]);


                    }


$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->fromArray($aRows);
$B1Style = array(
  'borders' => array(
    'allborders' => array(
      'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN
    )
  )
);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($aRows[4])->getStyle('B:E')->applyFromArray($B1Style);







$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A3')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
// Rename worksheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');


// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
// If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

// If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0


function cellColor($cells,$color){
    global $objPHPExcel;

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($cells)->getFill()->applyFromArray(array(
        'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
        'startcolor' => array(
             'rgb' => $color
        )
    ));
}

/*cellColor('A1:G1', 'F28A8C');
cellColor('B6:E6', 'F28A8C');
cellColor('B8:E8', 'F28A8C');*/



$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
ob_end_clean();
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
?>
```

i have got an array $aRows , as i want to create a border on item details row as item details repeats , i dont know what will be the cell name so how can i add rows into getstyle() instead of cell names .